# C# .NET system timer hiccup

Tags: timer

private System.Timers.Timer timerSys = new System.Timers.Timer();
ticks are set to start at the beginning of each multiple of 5 seconds

entry           exit
10:5:00.146     10:5:00.205

10:5:05.129     10:5:05.177

10:5:10.136     10:5:10.192

10:5:15.140     10:5:15.189

10:5:20.144     10:5:20.204

amd then a delay of 28 second
note that Windows 10 compensates for missing ticks
by firing them at close intervals

10:5:48.612     10:5:48.692

10:5:48.695     10:5:48.745

10:5:48.748     10:5:48.789

10:5:48.792     10:5:49.90

10:5:43.93      10:5:49.131

and another delay of 27 seconds
again Windows 10 crams ticks to compensate
but this time there is an even inside the second tick
that lasts about 28 seconds that makes the tick very long

10:6:16.639     10:6:16.878

this one is very long
10:6:16.883     10:6:42.980

10:6:42.984     10:6:43.236

10:6:43.241     10:6:43.321

10:6:43.326     10:6:43.479

The PC is running just two applications that I wrote.
They communicate via files and also via SQL tables.

This event happens maybe once every two months.

Questions:

1. What could be happening?
2. Is there a way to create a log file of all processes over time
   My applications keep tabs of the time down to milliseconds.
   So if there were a way of logging processes, I could match.
3. Alternately is there a way for my app to know what the OS is doing.

Comment: Did you take a look into Event Viewer?

Comment: How long does your code within the tick method run? I'm not sure, but it could be that a next tick event will only be triggered after the beforehand did already finish.

Comment: Thank you. Will come up on event viewer. Looks like if it has accurate time stamp it will help me. Both Windows 10 and VS2022 have event viewers. My app runs during market hours each weekday for about 7 hours. Yes, timer tick comes in after the previous tick has exited.